# Bat file set command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following

```
echo off
set installType = /t
set msBuild=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
set adminBuild = %msBuild% "d:\Projects\Test\Test.csproj" /T:Package /P:PackageLocation="d:\Projects\MSBuild\Package\Test.zip"
set adminDeploy = d:\Projects\MSBuild\Package\Test.deploy.cmd %installType%
echo %msBuild%
echo %adminBuild% 
echo %adminDeploy%
```

The first echo works correct, next ones don't return anything. Could you tell me what's wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have spaces on either side of the `=` in your `set` statements.

Use:

```
echo off
set installType = /t
set msBuild=c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
set adminBuild=%msBuild% "d:\Projects\Test\Test.csproj"...
set adminDeploy=d:\Projects\MSBuild\Package\Test.deploy.cmd %installType%
echo %msBuild%
echo %adminBuild% 
echo %adminDeploy%
```

which produces what you want:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "d:\Projects\Test\Test.csproj"...
d:\Projects\MSBuild\Package\Test.deploy.cmd
```